# Tidyr unnest function doesn't seem to do its work

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I'm trying to unlist a list column where each row only consists of an url.

I created a dataframe with metadata of file some files in a directory. This is my code:

```
df <- files_small %>% 
  keep(has_xattrs) %>% 
  set_names(basename(.)) %>% 
  map_df(read_xattrs, .id = "file") %>% 
  filter(name == "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms") %>% 
  mutate(url = map(files_small,
                          ~ read_bplist(
                            get_xattr_raw(path = .x,
                                          name = "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms")
                          ) 
  )) %>% 
  select(file, url)
```

That results in the following `dput`:

```
df <- structure(list(file = c("'s-Gravenhage_coalitieakkoord.pdf", 
"Aa en Hunze_coalitieakkoord.pdf"), url = list(structure(list(
    plist = structure(list(array = structure(list(string = list(
        "https://denhaag.raadsinformatie.nl/document/6514256/2/RIS299794%20Coalitieakkoord%202018%202022"), 
        string = list()), .Names = c("string", "string"))), .Names = "array", version = "1.0")), .Names = "plist"), 
    structure(list(plist = structure(list(array = structure(list(
        string = list("https://aaenhunze.vvd.nl/uploaded/aaenhunze.vvd.nl/files/5ad8cd44682d8/coalitieakkoord-2018-2022-_definitief_16-april.pdf"), 
        string = list()), .Names = c("string", "string"))), .Names = "array", version = "1.0")), .Names = "plist"))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .Names = c("file", 
"url"))


> unnest(df, url)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  file                              url       
  <chr>                             <list>    
1 's-Gravenhage_coalitieakkoord.pdf <list [1]>
2 Aa en Hunze_coalitieakkoord.pdf   <list [1]>
```

I want to unlist the list column, but `unnest(df, url)` doesn't seem to do its job. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several nested lists, try :

```
df %>% rowwise %>% mutate(x=unlist(url))

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#  file                              url        x                                                                                                                        
#  <chr>                             <list>     <chr>                                                                                                                    
#1 's-Gravenhage_coalitieakkoord.pdf <list [1]> https://denhaag.raadsinformatie.nl/document/6514256/2/RIS299794%20Coalitieakkoord%202018%202022                          
#2 Aa en Hunze_coalitieakkoord.pdf   <list [1]> https://aaenhunze.vvd.nl/uploaded/aaenhunze.vvd.nl/files/5ad8cd44682d8/coalitieakkoord-2018-2022-_definitief_16-april.pdf
```